# What were the original trail signs on the Toiyabe Crest Trail?

Tags: trails, history, signage, nevada

This summer I did the [Toiyabe Crest Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toiyabe_Range#Toiyabe_Crest_Trail) and noticed that there are three different kinds of trail signs:

- Cheap plastic triangular ones that say **Toiyabe Crest National Recreation Trail**
- Square posts with small signs that say **TCT ↑**
- Round posts with **Crest Trail** incised into them

I think that in order of age it went round, square and then plastic.

Seeing them made me wonder what the **original trail signs were back when the CCC built the trail.**

Comment: See  [Civilian Conservation Corps Park Road Signs](https://www.nps.gov/sagu/learn/historyculture/upload/CCC-Park-Road-Signs-Brief.pdf) for some original trail signs of the CCC in Arizona.